# Specification & Generalisation in ERD

Tags: sql, database, erd

I would appreciate if someone could clarify this confusion for me.I'm struggling to identified when to use each of them.

- Mandatory, OR/Mandatory, AND
- Optional, OR/Optional, AND

Thank you